# How do you convert WGS84 GPS coordinates to "SWEREF 99 TM" ones in JavaScript + Leaflet.js + proj4 + proj4leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, wgs84, proj4js, proj4leaflet

I have made a map system with JavaScript + Leaflet.js + proj4 + proj4leaflet. I'm trying to link to Lantmäteriet's map with the current position, but, of course, they don't use the "WGS84" standard, but instead the "SWEREF 99 TM" one. (Because we can't agree on a GPS coordinate system/standard, but require one incompatible one for every country/area on the planet.)

Example: https://minkarta.lantmateriet.se/?e=674816&n=6579072&z=7&background=2&boundaries=true

As you can see, it uses "e" and "n" instead of the "longitude" and "latitude" coordinates. They don't support WGS84 coordinates, so I have to somehow convert them before linking to the map. But how?

I've spent many hours searching online for this, but even the questions on Stack Exchange which ask about this just have nonsensical (at least to me) answers.

Is there not a simple converter function hidden inside "proj4" for this where I simply input a WGS84 longitude and get an "e" number back, and a WGS84 latitude and get a "n" number back? Isn't that exactly what "proj4" is supposed to be for?

Maybe this page somehow helps somebody to help me (but I doubt it): https://www.lantmateriet.se/en/maps-and-geographic-information/gps-geodesi-och-swepos/Referenssystem/Tvadimensionella-system/SWEREF-99-projektioner/

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code in the body of the question, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Outside links tend to get lost in time. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

Comment: @TomazicM Existing code is just the variables "longitude" and "latitude", which I thought was made obvious?

Comment: I suspect that "map system with JavaScript + Leaflet.js + proj4 + proj4leaflet" contains more JS code than just two variables.

Comment: @TomazicM My question has nothing to do with anything other than converting GPS coordinates.

Comment: Most of the times context of particular problem is as important as the problem itself. It greatly helps in giving you the right answer.

Comment: @TomazicM Please stop this nonsense. I have coordinates in one format and trying to convert them to another. Everything else is my private code and has exactly zero to do with this question.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.npmjs.com/package/proj4 the basic signature would be:

> proj4(fromProjection[, toProjection, coordinates])

Where

> Projections can be proj or wkt strings.

WKT for WGS84 (we'll assume EPSG:4326) is:

```
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",ENSEMBLE["World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble", MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)", ID["EPSG",1166]], MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)", ID["EPSG",1152]], MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)", ID["EPSG",1153]], MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)", ID["EPSG",1154]], MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)", ID["EPSG",1155]], MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)", ID["EPSG",1156]], ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.2572236,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]],ID["EPSG",7030]], ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2],ID["EPSG",6326]],CS[ellipsoidal,2,ID["EPSG",6422]],AXIS["Geodetic latitude (Lat)",north],AXIS["Geodetic longitude (Lon)",east],ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9102]],ID["EPSG",4326]]
```

and WKT for SWEREF 99 TM (EPSG:3006) is:

```
PROJCRS["SWEREF99 TM",BASEGEOGCRS["SWEREF99",DATUM["SWEREF99",ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]],ID["EPSG",7019]],ID["EPSG",6619]],ID["EPSG",4619]],CONVERSION["SWEREF99 TM",METHOD["Transverse Mercator",ID["EPSG",9807]],PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9102]]],PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",15,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9102]]],PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,SCALEUNIT["unity",1,ID["EPSG",9201]]],PARAMETER["False easting",500000,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]],PARAMETER["False northing",0,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]],ID["EPSG",17333]],CS[Cartesian,2,ID["EPSG",4500]],AXIS["Northing (N)",north],AXIS["Easting (E)",east],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]],ID["EPSG",3006]]
```

Comment: It just goes: `uncaught exception: PROJCRS["SWEREF99 TM",BASEGEOGCRS["SWEREF99",DATUM["SWEREF99",ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]],ID["EPSG",7019]],ID["EPSG",6619]],ID["EPSG",4619]],CONVERSION["SWEREF99 TM",METHOD["Transverse Mercator",ID["EPSG",9807]],PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9102]]],PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",15,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9102]]],PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,SCALEUNI...`

Comment: Nevermind. It works when I instead use `proj4.defs("EPSG:3006","+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs");`... Strange.

Comment: It may be expecting the older WKT format